# Azure stream analytics doesn't list custom endpoints in IoT Hub Source Input

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an IoT Hub with custom endpoints which sink data into service bus queues. Since i implemented custom routing through custom endpoints in IoT Hub & Service bus queues. When i try to create Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) job, the input panel in azure portal does not list custom endpoints but only consumer groups which work only for default messaging endpoint.

Is there a way to let ASA to pick messages off service bus queues or custom endpoints in IoT Hub so i do not need to modify custom routing i already have.

Thanks and looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) can access these endpoints. However they are not exposed when you select IoT Hub as input in ASA.
If you want to access these endpoints in ASA, you will need to point your ASA input to the Service Bus or Event Hub hosting these routes.
Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks,

JS